# Print self-documenting expression with value of variable on a new line

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

Python 3.8 allows for self-documenting expressions and debugging using `=`, e.g.:

```
print(f'{myvar=}')
```

Is it possible to print the output on a new line? This would be useful for variables with multi-line outputs like dataframes, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['alligator', 'bee', 'falcon', 'lion', 'monkey']})

print(f'{df=}')
```

```
df =
      animal
0  alligator
1        bee
2     falcon
3       lion
4     monkey
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make your f string triple-quoted, you can include a newline after the `=`:

```
print(f'''{df=
}''')
```

Answer (score 3):

Using triple quotes works, but it causes some trouble when the print statement is in an indented block:

```
if True:
    if True:
        # ...some code with indentation...
        print(f"""{df =
}""")
        # ...more code with indentation...
```

Note that one does not simply indent the `}"""` part to the proper level, without breaking the formatting of the first line of the f-string.

### Single line solution

#### Python 3.12+

Python 3.12 introduced [syntactic formalization of f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#pep-701-syntactic-formalization-of-f-strings), which allows for nested f-strings.
This allows us to use the following construct to achieve what we want.

```
NL = '\n'
print(f"{f"{NL}{df}" = !s}")
```

Which outputs:

```
f"{NL}{df}" =
      animal
0  alligator
1        bee
2     falcon
3       lion
4     monkey
```

#### Python <3.12

I asked a similar question, and found a single line solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61750896/12431520), which I am writing here as well, for reference.

```
def f_str_nl(obj):
    return f"\n{obj!r}"

print(f"{f_str_nl(df) = !s}")
```

which outputs:

```
f_str_nl(df) = 
      animal
0  alligator
1        bee
2     falcon
3       lion
4     monkey
```

This method does not cause problems with indented blocks.
However, the name of the object in the f-string gets wrapped with the function name, `f_str_nl()`.

Answer (score 2):

To include a newline inside the f-string, like in [Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58685914/4518341), but have it in one line, I use `eval`:

```
print(eval('f"""{df=\n}"""'))
```

```
df=
      animal
0  alligator
1        bee
2     falcon
3       lion
4     monkey
```

Use triple-single quotes to allow single-quotes inside, for example:

```
print(eval('''f"""{df.query('animal.str.contains("e")')=\n}"""'''))
```

```
df.query('animal.str.contains("e")')=
   animal
1     bee
4  monkey
```

If you include a conversion, it needs to go after the newline (e.g. ...`\n!s}`...), otherwise you get a `SyntaxError`. Same for a format spec, but with a `ValueError` you'd get from a non-eval'd f-string.

I put it in a code snippet so I don't have to type/remember the whole thing every time. For VSCode:

```json
"Dead-simple debug using f-string with newline before value": {
    "prefix": "debug-fstring-newline",
    "body": "print(eval('''f\"\"\"DEBUG: {${1:<expression>}=\\n${2:!${3:<conversion>}}${4::${5:<format_spec>}}}\"\"\"'''))",
},
```

---

P.S. I initially tried inserting a newline via a variable, but this syntax is invalid:

```
NL = '\n'
print(f"{df={NL}}")
```

Comment: using triple double-quotes for the f-string part does not seem to be necessary after python 3.12, as the expression is already single line, and f-string expressions can contain the same type of quotes within them after python 3.12.